# How should I write a SQLite query so it searches for strings in a database that match strings in a string array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite

I have a database that holds recipes. I want to be able to search the database for recipes by ingredients. So, if I search for "apple", it should pull up all the recipes that have the word "apple" in the column "ingredients."

Example of table
Name: "Apple pie"
Ingredients: "apple flour sugar etc."

At first, when it searched the database, I had it set up so that the inputText was just a string. For example, the inputText would be like "apple flour." But, I thought maybe it would make more sense if it took the inputText and put it in a String Array (but I could be totally wrong). So, it would be more like this: ("apple", "flour").

But, my issue is that I don't know how I would write the query so that it looks in the ingredients column for any string that matches one in the array.

Also, should I make it so that the strings in the ingredients column are arrays as well? Because right now they're just strings separated by spaces.

Here's what my query looks like now, which I know isn't right

```
public Cursor fetchRecipesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.w(TAG, inputText);
        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
                            COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_SPECIAL, COLUMN_DESCRIPT, COLUMN_ALLINGRED, COLUMN_INSTRUCT, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {

            mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
                            COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_SPECIAL, COLUMN_DESCRIPT, COLUMN_ALLINGRED, COLUMN_INSTRUCT, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                    COLUMN_INGRED + " like '%" + inputText + "%'",
                    null, null, null, null, null);

        }
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried running this? Does it throw any errors?

Comment: There's no array data type in sqlite.  So either do something like what you have now, or split ingredients into its own table.

Comment: In your case (sqlite), your solution is fine. If you need a little bit more http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

Comment: But it doesn't really work. It will only search for certain words which is weird. Like if I search for "salmon honey", it will work. but if I search "honey salmon" it won't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The correct way

What you have is a multi to multi relationship. Ie, you have many recipes which can each have many ingredients... or you have many ingredients which can be in many recipes.

The best way to handle the multi-to-multi relationship is by having 3 tables. One for your recipes, one for your ingredients, and one for relations.

For your `Recipes` Table, let's say you have columns `_id` and `name` (and others, but those aren't relevant)

For `Ingredients` Table, you would also have `_id` and `name` (and again, lets ignore other columns for this example)

For the relations table, say `RecipesAndIngredients`, you would have columns `recipe_id` and `ingredient_id`

Then to search for ingredients named 'apple' and 'flour', your end-result 
SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT _id,name FROM Recipes
    JOIN RecipesAndIngredients
        ON RecipesAndIngredients.recipe_id=Recipes._id
    JOIN Ingredients
        ON Ingredients.id = RecipesAndIngredients.ingredient_id
WHERE Ingredients.name LIKE 'apple%' OR Ingredients.name LIKE 'flour%'
GROUP BY Recipes._id
```

I'm not going to work this into an Android-friendly example, but it is the correct way to do it.

### The easy way

Use someone else's answer.

**Why not use the easy way?**

- Performance. Search will be slower because indexes cannot be used for `LIKE
  '%abc'`, and you will have to use `LIKE '%abc%'` for everything since
  you wouldn't know WHERE in the ingredients list the 'abc' is.
- Consistency. There are a finite number of ingredients, and storing strings means you could end up with 'flour', 'floor', 'fluur' or whatever else. By using a separate table, users could first search for an ingredient before adding it.
- Data access. I'm not gonna get into it, but you have way more options for accessing your data, such as "how many recipes have apples in them?" or "What recipes have 3 of the same ingredients that are in THIS RECIPE?".
- Learning. Using my way will help you learn databases as well as Android. The easy way will only really help with learning Android.

**Why use the easy way?**

- It's easier. You already have the code written.
- Less Learning. It will also keep you from learning about databases, which I see as a bad thing because databases are great. But, if you don't want to learn databases right now, then my approach won't be very good for you.
- Overwhelming...ness. Learning how databases work is different than learning how Java/Android works, and trying to understand it can be a bit overwhelming.

### Notes

- There are third party database libraries/tools available. I
  personally recommend using one, such as Greendao or SugarORM. Then you won't have to do any real databasing.
- Threading/Synchronization sucks with Android SQL, and seemingly random errors pop up as a result. I made [this project](https://github.com/JakarCo/databasemanager) to solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I understand what you're saying with your approach. I wish I would've done that from the beginning...unfortunately, I am at bit of a time constraint so I'm not sure if I would have the time to restructure everything. So, I will probably just stick with the easy way.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you named the array which contains ingredients you want to search, ings. I mean ings is the string array you build from splitting inputText.

You can do this:

```
String qr = "";
for(int i=0; i<ings.length; i++{
    String tmp = COLUMN_INGRED + " LIKE ?"
    ings[i] = "%" + ings[i] + "%";
    qr += tmp;
    if(i != ings.size()-1) qr += " OR ";
}
 mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID,
                        COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, 
                        COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_SPECIAL, 
                        COLUMN_DESCRIPT, COLUMN_ALLINGRED, 
                        COLUMN_INSTRUCT, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                        qr,
                        ings, null, null, null, null);
```

I again mention that the type of ings is `String[]`.

Comment: You have `like %?%` which should be `like '%?%'`. I also feel like it's good to use upper case for SQL keywords to help separate SQL from paramaters and such. Ie: `OR val LIKE 'like'` is easier to read than `or val like 'like'`, but that's my own personal preference.

Comment: @Jakar you are right about cases, I fixed them. But you should know that android sqlite drive will automatically add quotations. My script had a problem, inside query I can't use %?%. the % character should be around word and I fixed it too.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to write the question mark after the "like" part and the percent % after the searched word, so your `mCursor` must look something like this:

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {COLUMN_ROWID, COLUMN_NAME, 
                          COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_INGRED, COLUMN_SPECIAL, COLUMN_DESCRIPT, 
                          COLUMN_ALLINGRED, COLUMN_INSTRUCT, COLUMN_IMGPATH},
                          COLUMN_INGRED + " LIKE '?'", new String[]{inputText+"%"}, 
                          null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have never used it, your usage of the `LIKE` clause looks fine. There may be some ways you could improve on your method, but it should work. If you are looking to search for several ingredients that appear in a `String[]`, then perhaps you could try something like this (this is untested, just an idea):

To get your `String[]` composed of your user's search input, split into separate search terms:

```
String[] splitStringBySpace(String userEditTextInput){
    if (userEditTextInput.trim().equals("") { 
        return new String[0];
    }
    return userEditTextInput.trim().split("\\s+");
}
```

Then use it inside your revised method:

```
public Cursor fetchRecipesByName(String whereArgsNotSplit) throws SQLException {

        String[] whereArgs = splitStringBySpace(whereArgsNotSplit);

        Cursor returnCursor = null;

        if (whereArgs == null || whereArgs.length == 0) {
            return returnCursor;
         }
/*
*Exit early if whereArgs is empty or null. If you want to return a full cursor here, 
*then you can return a query() with all parameters set to null except for the 
*SQLITE_TABLE.
*/
        SQLiteDatabase mDb = this.getReadableDatabase(); //We are only reading the database
        StringBuilder selection = new StringBuilder(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < whereArgs.length; i++) {
            whereArgs[i] = "'%" + whereArgs[i].trim() + "%'"
            if (i == 0) {
               selection.append(COLUMN_INGRED + " LIKE ?");
            } else {                
               selection.append(" OR LIKE ?")
            }
        }
//This for loop will construct the data for our WHERE clause in the query method.

         returnCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, null,
                        selection.toString(),
                        whereArgs, null, null, null, null); //Using whereArgs parameter

            }
            return returnCursor;
    }
```

Comment: Okay, I'll test it out. But how would change this:         `customCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(String[] constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchRecipesByName(constraint);
            }
        });`

to implement that. I get an error on the new FilterQueryProvider() part

Comment: Take a look at my edit for an idea. If you want to use this method, it looks like you can't pass an `array` argument - which is fine, it just means a slight restructuring.

Comment: I'm trying it out now but for some reason I'm getting an error: `Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.`

Comment: This may be a result of the issue Roozbeh identified in his answer. I have edited my post to incorporate his solution.